# Kendo Grid MVC Sample - Remote Data Binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I am new to using Kendo UI Grid. I am looking at the MVC samples and am not able to figure out how remote binding sample is passing model from controller to the view:

Controller Code:

```
public partial class GridController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Remote_Data_Binding()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity).Width(150);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)
```

In the view code there is no @model specified and in the controller there is no model passed in View method. How then does the grid populate the data?

Comment: It's using Ajax (~/Grid/Orders_Read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fruitbat has said Kendo uses ajax to populate grids. This is all configured in the grids datasource . Here is some documentation that is worth looking over.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#read